# How to check if CPU is dying?

Tags: cpu

Today began a problem on my CPU. The temperature is high (70C at startup, going higher with time) and the ressource monitor indicates that the frequency and CPU usage is rubber banding between 0 and 100.

In addition, softwares that used to run fine yesterday are now lagging. Everything in a software that may be consuming in normal time is now impossible to use. The sound has white noise cutting in, repetitions. Animations are going back and forth instead of running smoothly. The computer runs slower in general (sometimes, it even has delay with the keyboard, even to write this message the letters are not instantly displayed as it usually would be)

The CPU temperature alerted me. It is watercooled so I checked inside and nothing seems wrong, the pipe that goes out from the water CPU module is really hot but the watercooling fan is running at top speed and cold water comes in from the other pipe.

Is there a test I can run to know for sure the CPU is dying (it should not, it is around two years old but I guess it can happen) before buying another one ?

Comment: The first thing I would do is clean out the heatsink attached to the CPU and re-paste the join between the CPU and heatsink. The usual culprit for an overheating CPU is clogged heatsink and old/cracked/dried paste not providing optimal heat trasnfer from CPU to heatsink/cooling mechanism.

Comment: There are stress tests etc which may give you an indication. EG https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/19792/Intel-Processor-Diagnostic-Tool and prime95

Comment: 70C while water cooled means you have a cooling problem your CPU is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested, I tried to investigate the cooling system. The thermal paste was dry and only chunks of it left. Replaced it and it works fine again. I still have no clue on why the CPU went mad and not only hot, and why it was fine on the evening and stopped working the next morning. But thanks